# Laravel / Excel Parsing / RegExp not firing

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel, parsing

I'm using Laravel and the using MaatWebsite/Laravel-Excel module to read in an Excel file, processes rows, assign variables and put into a database.

Because the input files vary, slightly (different column orders, not always the same number of columns), I've put together this code that tries to make those details unnecessary.

**Note:** this script works most of the time (other files) and is currently processing a particular file (structure below) but the values are somehow getting assigned improperly.

I'm showing the relevant portions of my code:

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($filename)->chunk(50, function($results) {
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        foreach(array_keys($row) as $k) {
            switch (1) {
                case preg_match('/attended/i', $k):
                break;

                // many other cases

                case (preg_match('/morning/i', $k)):
                     // dd($row[$k]);  // doesn't run here either
                     if($row[$k] !== null){
                          $morning = $row[$k];
                          dd($row[$k]);
                     }
                break;
                case (preg_match('/afternoon/i', $k)):
                     if($row[$k] !== null ){
                         $afternoon = $row[$k];
                         dd($row[$k]);
                     }
                break;
        }
        // processing of the row
    }
});
```

I have slipped lines of `dd($something);` into places to prove that what I'm expecting to see is, in fact, being seen.

The following is the array that I get by looking at the first row of data in the file:

```
array:49 [▼
  "attended" => "Yes"
  "salutation" => "Mr"
  "first_name" => "First"
  "last_name" => "Last"
  "suffix" => null
  "email" => "email@address.com"
  "ticket" => "Non Member - Friday Only"
  "seats" => 1.0
  "registered_on" => "3/14/2017"
  "registered_by" => "Full Name"
  "payment" => "At the Door"
  "confirmation_code" => "PRO - 60240/1"
  "payment_received" => "Yes"
  "status" => "Active"
  "cancelled_on" => null
  "cost" => 0.0
  "cc_charge" => 0.0
  "handling_fee" => 0.0
  "your_amount" => 0.0
  "disc_code" => "Sponsor"
  "disc_description" => "Sponsor"
  "disc_amount" => -375.0
  "morning_keynote_friday_815_am_945_am" => null
  "breakout_1_friday_1000_am_1130_am" => null
  "breakout_2_friday_130_pm_300_pm" => null
  "breakout_3_friday_315_pm_415_pm" => null
  "networking_and_cocktail_session_500_pm_600_pm" => null
  "friday_evening_dinner_with_speaker_600_pm_830_pm" => null
  "breakout_1_saturday_800_am_900_am" => null
  "breakout_2_saturday_915_am_1215_pm" => null
  "breakout_3_saturday_215_pm_445_pm" => null
  "please_list_any_dietary_requirements_gluten_free_lactose_vegetarian_etc" => null
  "would_you_like_your_name_and_company_name_added_to_the_roster_made_available_to_participants" => "Yes"
  "what_is_your_company_name" => null
  "select_your_chapter_affiliation" => "Not a current member"
  "please_list_any_special_arrangements_required_to_attend_this_event_wheelchair_access_etc" => null
  "do_not_use_2" => null
  "do_not_use_3" => null
  "do_not_use" => null
  "do_not_use_4" => null
  "do_not_use_5" => null
  "what_morning_session_are_you_attending" => null
  "what_afternoon_session_are_you_attending_if_in_all_day_class_please_select_the_same" => null
  "which_morning_session_are_you_attending2" => null
  "which_afternoon_session_are_you_attending2" => null
  "what_morning_session_are_you_attending3" => "Session Name I want to capture"
  "what_afternoon_session_are_you_attending3" => "Another Session Name I want to capture"
```

Because of the inefficient way that the data was captured, I'm looking for a "morning" value that could appear in any of those final 3 values and I also want an "afternoon" value.

I'm finding that, though clearly a regexp should trigger for morning and/or afternoon, the dd() statements I've inserted above do not ever get triggered.

Any insight the mistake occurring here?

Comment: Probably not the solution but the switch statement in the example looks to be missing a closing brace.

Comment: You are correct that it's missing in the excerpt above, but it is compiling & running in the real code.